# changing the num-lock functionality

Tags: keyboard, desktop-customization

I'd like to change the way numlock works on my keyboard.  What I want is for it to act like caps lock for my number row.  His way I can type parens and other characters while programming without having to use shift to get the job done.  Anybody have any advice?

Answer (score 2):

I think it's possible to script this entire thing via the AutoHotKey. Since you're a programmer, it should be easy for you.

And this is a really good idea, thanks! :3

Comment: Yeah, autoHotKey came to mind but I'm rarely on windows.  Trying to decide on a good way to do this on linux and osx as well.  Also I'm not sure how this would work as I don't have a ten key pad so numlock actually changes some letters to numbers.  I'll have to look and see how you disable that.  Great suggestion just not quite what I'm looking for.

Comment: @JasonTholstrup should specify OS then